# ASP image rotator

Tags: asp-classic, image-rotation

So I'm pretty new to ASP, and want to use a script like this:
http://www.w3schools.com/ASP/showasp.asp?filename=demo_adrotator

To randomly load an image when the page is loaded, but I don't want to link it. Any thoughts on how I can modify the example to be a simple  rotator?

Answer (score 1):

If all your images are named the same with a number difference, here's a quick way to do it:

```
<img src="images/img<%= Int(Rnd * 6)+1 %>.jpg" />
```

In this scenario, your pictures are all in the images folder are are called img#.jpg where # ranges from 1 to 6.

But to be honest, you don't really need ASP to do this. You could just use javascript to get the random url.

Comment: right now I only have 2 images, but I can only get one of them to load with this (img2.jpg)

Comment: Well, is the other image called 'img1.jpg'? If so, make sure that the +1 is OUTSITE the () brackets.

Comment: yeah it's strange, I have img1.jpg and img2.jpg in the images folder, but this: <img src="images/img<%= Int(Rnd * 2)+1 %>.jpg" /> is only loading img2.jpg. I tried refreshing a bunch of times and in a different browser.

Comment: As Dee said, make sure you declare the random function before with `Randomize`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method mentioned in the comments

< img src="images/img<%= Int(Rnd * 2)+1 %>.jpg" / >

but you must first declare the Randomize statement or it will always return the same number

< % Randomize %>

< img src="images/img<%= Int(Rnd * 2)+1 %>.jpg" / >